# Visual Studio 2017 hangs for 2, 3 minutes before starting build

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio 2017 professional hangs for about 2, 3 minutes before starting the build of my WPF application (and then showing "Build started..."). With VS 2015, it hung after the build (before Starting the application), now it hangs before the build. Did anyone face the same problem?

Comment: What does the output window show when VS hangs ?

Comment: "Hangs 2 minutes before": how would VS know you are going to do a built in 2 minutes time? Or do you mean "hangs *for* 2 minutes"?

Comment: Sure, it hangs FOR 2 minutes, I fixed the header, thanks!

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it btw. since I posted here, I'll get back to the question concerning the output window. I thought it showed just nothing before starting the build and showing "Build started...".

Comment: Not the kind of answer we like to hear but after reinstalling my PC, everything is lightning-fast, no problems in Visual Studio 2017 anymore.

Comment: Starting on October 31, 2017, Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.1) started hanging during Build / Solution.

A quick glance at Task Manager reveals VS 2017 using 77% of the CPU.  Memory consumption is approximately 600MB (19% overall), with nothing else except Notepad.exe running.

Comment: Yes, 2017 community. I am getting a smell that it seems to have something to do with leaving the cursor at the point I just finished typing.